# Why is this printing twice in perl?

Tags: perl, printing

So I'm hoping somebody can just explain to my why when I run the following code, it prints ".link/output" at both the beginning and end of the line.  I was trying to get it to print only at the end of the line.  Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my $logfiles = $ARGV[0]; #file containing the list of all the log file names

my @logf = ();
my $i;

open (F2, "<", $logfiles);

while(<F2>){
    @logf = $_;
    foreach $i(@logf){
        print $_.".link/output";

    }
}
close F2;
```

So for example, if the file I'm reading in is:

```
cat
dog
```

I want to see:

```
cat.link/output
dog.link/output
```

But isntead I am getting:

```
.link/outputcat.link/output
.link/outputdog.link/output
```

Could anybody please explain to me why this is happening and/or how to fix it?  Thank you.

Comment: Empty element in your list, I think. It's concatenating ".link/output" to an empty string.

Comment: Can you confirm that your `while` and `foreach` loops are executing the expected number of times?

Comment: Why do you assign a scalar to an array, and then try to loop over the array? It can only ever contain ONE value, so no loop is literally ever needed. And in the loop, you do not even use the loop variable `$i`, you use `$_` anyway. `@logf = $_; for $i (@logf) { print $_ . ... }` All this is completely redundant. You might as well just write `print "$_.link/output\n" while <F2>`

Comment: This program *cannot* produce the output you claim it does. You really *must* post the real code for us to be able to help you properly. Fix it as it stands by adding `chomp` as the first statement in the `while` loop, and adding `, "\n"` to the end of the `print` statement.

Comment: @Borodin I Directly copied and pasted the code that I was using.  And the problem has already been solved, but thank you.

Comment: @user1440061: you do not strip the newlines coming from your input file yet they do not appear in your output. Other people may turn to this question for help so please explain how you fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have an empty element at the beginning of your list. simply `shift @logf`

Comment: Where should i put that line?

Comment: I suggest right after you assign `@logf`. Also, make it local to the loop, for good coding practices are good.

Comment: Correction: he has an empty line at the beginning of his log file. There can literally not be more than one element in the array each iteration. Although the expected newlines do not match the supposed output.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what `@logf` does. Couldn't you just do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my $logfiles = $ARGV[0]; #file containing the list of all the log file names

#open(my $f2, "<", $logfiles);

# FOR TESTING, use above in your code
my $f2 = \*DATA;
# ===========

while(<$f2>){
        chomp;
        print "$_.link/output\n";
}
__DATA__
cat
dog
```

Comment: +1 Though you should say that `@logf` is redundant instead, since it clearly is.

Comment: I could see that it wasn't doing much (other than causing problems), but I wanted to the give OP a chance to say "oh I need that for Y".